# How to replace a charecter in a string with another ?? in c++

Tags: c++

This is my code, but it says `replace is not declared in this scope` isn't this the correct syntax??

```
#include<iostream>                                                                          
#include<string>                                                                            


using namespace std;                                                                        

int  main ()                                                                                
{                                                                                           
  string string_to_edit;                                                                    
  cout<<"Enter a string to replace all the vowels:"<<endl;                                  
  cin>>string_to_edit;                                                                      
  string output_string=replace(string_to_edit.begin(),string_to_edit.end(),"a","x");               
  cout<<output_string<<endl;                                                                
  return 0;                                                                                 
}
```

Comment: `#include <algorithm>`

Comment: got error with #include <algorithm>

Comment: Post the *exact* error by editing your original question.

Comment: i got it with @juanchopanza answer thank you all :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to `#include <algorithm>` for [`std::replace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/replace), but you also need to use single characters. Note the single quotes:

```
replace(string_to_edit.begin(),string_to_edit.end(),'a','x');
```

Also note that `replace` will replace the elements in place. `std::replace` returns `void`.

Answer (score 3):

`std::replace` is [declared in `<algorithm>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/replace), so you have to `#include <algorithm>`

You also need to make two other changes:

1. `replace` returns `void`, so if you want the `replace`d string to be seperate from the original string, you need to make a copy of the original and pass that to `replace`.
2. `replace` takes single `char`s, not strings; but you are passing a nulll-terminated string with `"a"` and `"x"`.

Code incorporating both of these changes:

```
std::string output_string = string_to_edit;
replace (output_string.begin(), output_string.end(), 'a', 'x');
```

Comment: @JohnDibling: You don't need to; he posted his code. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e1b1faa481eeec58

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit:  Ah, I didn't see that before.